# where is FACTORY_FOR in a factory boy django factory?

Tags: python, django, factory-boy

I am using Factory Boy in a Django project and I need to access class properties, defined in the class, in the corresponding factory.

My test case has something along the lines of:

```
from django.test.testcases import TransactionTestCase
from app.tests.factories import SomeModelFactory

class MyTestCase(TransactionTestCase):   
    def test_something(self):
        ...
        SomeModelFactory.create(
            data_type=SomeModelFactory.FACTORY_FOR.TYPE_STRING)
        ...
```

My class, as you may guess, has the corresponding constant in the right spot.

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
  TYPE_STRING = 2
  ...
```

and the corresponding factory is defined as it should be

```
class SomeModelFactory(factory.Factory):
  FACTORY_FOR = SomeModel
  ...
```

The test case fails saying that `FACTORY_FOR` is not there. So, I think the *metaclass* is hidding that somewhere. Ideally, I would like to minimise the need to **import** the model directly if I am using the factory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SomeModelFactory._associated_class` should be what you are looking for...

Comment: thanks. Looks like something not officially available. Is that part of the API or just back-door access? If unofficial, I will keep the import model waiting for a public API for that.